# Where can I get the source files of the CD label?

Tags: cd

Where can I get the source files of this CD label

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DIYMarketing#Current%20DIYMarketing%20content:

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they're available. The finalized PDF was uploaded by Canonical's Marketing Coordinator, which means the actual production of the document was probably done through channels internal to Canonical. A professional design team does not publish its source files.

With that said, I just tried importing the PDF into [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/inkscape)) and it did such a good job it practically *is* the source file. Definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a few hours/days and I'm sure you will find them at http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/